# Cognos Cast ParamValue(text_box_input) as number

Tags: cognos-10

Can I cast a ParamValue(text_box_result) as a currency or value?

The user will input a number like below in the text box:

```
101.03
107
109.1
7653.9
```

and I need it to return :

```
$101.03
$107.00
$109.10
$7,653.90
```

The style does not work to change to currency, I assume because it is an uncasted text box....

Comment: When you explain the return, just to clarify this is still the text box prompt?
Could you share more about the report design?
For example, you could have a text item that shows in whatever format you want
Or are you looking for javascript to change the presentation?
What is the significance of showing the $ in the prompt?
When the report is distributed, is this shown?  Or is this interactive and the user is confused by the currency type

Comment: @VAI Jason, thanks, I decided to leave it as is.  Thank you!